# Using xunit or nunit as test runner framework

Tags: .net, nunit, xunit

I'll start with an problem. I have a little library. It goes through a list of urls in text files and create assertions depending on the url returns 200 or not.

The goal is to make a test runner like Reshaprer, Testdriven.net or a CI server like team city or hudson to pick up the assertions as tests.

My question is how do I extend/build upon xunit or nunit to run tests from another source?
Examples would be great.

**Update**
To make things a bit more clear.
I should be able to look load the dll in the test runner that ships with xunit/nunit and run the test.

How the list of urls is populated is very dynamic. Depending on certain things more url can be created. So a list of data is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean how can you run NUnit tests programmatically (instead of using one of the supplied NUnit runners), then it's actually pretty easy:

```
using System;
using NUnit.Core;
using NUnit.Framework;
using MyProject.Tests;  /* assuming MyTestFixture is defined in this project/assembly */

namespace TestRunner.DemoApp {
    class Program {

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var builder = new TestSuiteBuilder();
        var testAssemblyLocation = typeof(MyTestFixture).Assembly.Location;
        var package = new TestPackage(testAssemblyLocation);
        var suite = builder.Build(package);
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.WriteLine("Running tests from " + testAssemblyLocation;
        Console.WriteLine("Testing against " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostNameSuffix"]);
        var result = suite.Run(new NullListener(), TestFilter.Empty);
        switch (result.ResultState) {
            case ResultState.Success:
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.WriteLine("Pass.");
                break;
            case ResultState.Error:
            case ResultState.Failure:
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                DrawResults(result.Results, r => r.ResultState == ResultState.Error || r.ResultState == ResultState.Failure);
                break;
        }

        static void DrawResults(IList results, Func<TestResult, bool> include) {
            foreach (var obj in results) {
                var result = obj as TestResult;
                if (result == null) continue;
                if (result.Results != null && result.Results.Count > 0) {
                    DrawResults(result.Results, include);
                } else if (include(result)) {
                    Console.WriteLine(result.Name);
                    Console.WriteLine(result.Message);
                    Console.WriteLine(result.ResultState);
                    Console.WriteLine(result.StackTrace);
                    Console.WriteLine(String.Empty.PadLeft(Console.WindowWidth, '='));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really what I was looking for. I don't need to build a test runner. I need to run test in nunits test runner.

Answer (score 1):

With xUnit, all you need is to implement `ITestRunner` interface, i.e.:

```
public class MyTestRunner : ITestRunner
{
    // Methods
    public MyTestRunner();
    public static TestRunState RunAssembly(TestRunner runner);
    public static TestRunState RunClass(TestRunner runner, Type type);
    public static TestRunState RunClassWithInnerTypes(TestRunner runner, Type type);
    public static TestRunState RunMethod(TestRunner runner, MethodInfo method);
    TestRunState ITestRunner.RunAssembly(ITestListener listener, Assembly assembly);
    TestRunState ITestRunner.RunMember(ITestListener listener, Assembly assembly, MemberInfo member);
    TestRunState ITestRunner.RunNamespace(ITestListener listener, Assembly assembly, string ns);
}
```

For implementation details, grab the source code of xUnit and have a look at the sample runners.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`TestCaseSourceAttribute`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5) in NUnit to run dynamic tests.